# Using grep in while loop breaks the loop

Tags: bash, loops, grep

I want to write a script in bash that prints the least repeating line of standard input

I wrote this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=1000
while read line
do
    tmp=$(grep -c $line)
    if [ $tmp -lt $var ]
    then
        var=$tmp
        out=$line
    fi
done
var="$var $out"
echo $var
```

but e.g. when using a test like this

```
id1
id2
id3
id1
square
id1
id2
id3
id1
circle
id2
id2
```

the program only enters the loop once thus it gives a bad output

```
3 id1
```

when the correct one should be

```
1 square
```

This line

```
tmp=$(grep -c $line)
```

seems to be breaking the loop but I can't find out why.
Is there any way to bypass using grep in my code or any other way to fix my script?

Comment: Why is `circle` your expected output? It is neither the last repeating nor the last unique line in your example.

Comment: It should be the least repeating, not the last repeating ;)
Still, your answer below helped me a lot ;)

Comment: So do you mean the first unique line, then? You have multiple unique lines; theyare all the least repeating.

Comment: No, i guess my English skills didn't let me make this clear enough, if there is a unique line in the stdin it should also print it, let's say we have a one line containing word: square , two lines containing word: circle and three lines containing word: triangle. It should print "square" because it only appears once in the file (appears the least amount of times)

Comment: That much is clear, but if there is three of each, do you only want the first one?

Comment: Yes, i only want the first one then, I solved it like this:

head -n 1 < <(sort -n < <((uniq -c)< <(sort)))
(i know it would be much easier using pipes, but i'm not allowed to use them)

Comment: Sorting will change the order. If you genuinely want the first one, I'd suggest Awk, especially if pipes are not tolerated (sic!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that this `grep`

> ```
>     tmp=$(grep -c $line)
> ```

will read from *stdin* and thus consume all the lines on the very first round the while loop is executed. I.e. first you will `read` the first line into `$line`. Then you will `grep` for this string in the rest of the *stdin*.

You could fix your code by using a temporary file, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
cat > "$tmpfile"
min=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    count=$(grep -c "$line" $tmpfile)
    if (( min == 0 || (count < min) )); then
        min=$count
        out="$min $line"
    fi
done < <(sort -u "$tmpfile")
rm "$tmpfile"
echo "$out"
```

But this is of course quite horrible solution as it uses temporary file and opens the input file many times. Better would be to use something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sort | uniq -c | sort -n | head -1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` command reads the remainder of standard input. You will need to copy the input to a temp file if you want to both `grep` it and do something else with it.

A much simpler solution to your problem is

```
uniq -d | tail -n 1
```

More generally, running `grep` on each line in a loop over a file is at antipattern which often suggests moving to Awk or `sed` instead, if you can't find a simple pipeline with standard tools to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot!